# Javascript framework: Knockout, backbone, ember…

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, ember.js

I'm currently on a web application project written in javascript with node.js and Express server-side and it's time to consider the client-side of this application. The two questions are:

- Should I consider using a framework or can I write it without such a tool?
- And if not, which framework?

I've chosen three of these: backbone, knockout and Ember. I read all the questions I found about them but I'm still hesitating. The points to consider are:

- It is good to mix html with javascript like knockout does?
- Will my application be easily maintainable?
- Will the framework continue and not diappear tomorrow, leaving me in a very uncomfortable situation?

**EDIT**: And what do you think about JavaScriptMVC?

Comment: I do understand youre point, and you're quite right, but my question is more about the practices each one induces. For example the javascript/html mixing of knockout and so on… And as I'm quite new in web dev, if it is crazy to think making an app without frameworks.

Comment: @MartinGOYOT i don't think it's crazy creating a web app without frameworks when your just starting with web development. i actually recommend this because you will be able to see how things work internally. it depends on the project really. if is a small project and you don't have a deadline try to do without one. it will help you in the long term. a framework should be used when you realize that it's pointless to reinvent the wheel for each project and you understand what the framework does and how does it help you speed up the development process.

Comment: There are answer to each of your question thrown as bits and pieces here on Stack network of sites. I will give you some time before citing the links. At the end of day i will have taught a person to search for good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Christian Varga has said in the comments, it depends. However, I would make the following observations:

> It is good to mix html with javascript like knockout does?

With knockout you are not forced to mix javascript into the html. See [Unobstrusive Event Handling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html).

> Will my application be easily maintainable?

In my experience with knockout , if the application gets especially large the pages do get complicated. However, if you are going for a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) style page then the code will always get fairly involved. I haven't worked with Ember or Backbone but certainly Backbone does have a reputation for being be good for larger applications.

> Will the framework continue and not diappear tomorrow, leaving me in a
>   very uncomfortable situation?

I think you have picked your three frameworks to consider wisely. Knockout and Backbone both have fairly wide adoption. Knockout is to be [shipped with MVC4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVC4ASPNETWebAPIAndASPNETWebPagesV2RazorNowAllOpenSourceWithContributions.aspx) which gives you some confidence behind its future. Ember is newer but there seems to be a lot of excitement behind it. There is a good discussion of Ember with various references to knockout and backbone [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3739260)

Hope this helps you evaluate what will be best for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and the articles linked which are very useful and interesting. I'm really here to try to make my opinion on the differents options I have, not to find the virtually best solution.

Answer (score 0):

All those are good frameworks. You can choose anyone and you won't make a huge mistake. Of course, you might like one most than others, but that's a matter of taste. All those frameworks will make your app easy mantainable.

Now, I want to add something more. You asked "Should I consider using a framework"? You can build your own stuff, that's something cool. I'd just recomend to keep in mind good organization of your project. In my short experience, Js is a mess. And these FWs help you to keep your code clean and organized.

1 more thing to add to organization: You should consider some AMD tool, like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of building an application with scalability and maintainability in mind you might want to consider a reference architecture such as [Boilerplatejs](http://boilerplatejs.org/).

BoilerplateJS incorporates best practices to be used when building a large scale application. Furthermore it ships with libraries such as knockoutjs and also utilities that would help structure and organize your code.